# Printing HTML page and color changes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I want my anchor tags to remain blue in color when I print it. Currently, when I print my webpage, the color of the anchor tag and everything (but images) changes to black. Here is the CSS I used

```
    @media print {
    a:link:after,
    a:visited:after {
        content: "" !important;
    }

    @media print {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }

 .content{
    font-style: italic;
    color:  #909090;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;

 }
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code included that affects link colors, in print or otherwise. So either you have other code that sets them black, or your print settings cause that.

Comment: By Default, html links are blue. Print preview shows the black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media print {
a,
a:link:after,
a:visited:after {
    content: "" !important;
    color: blue; /* or whatever color you want */
}
```